# PIL resize image returns NoneType

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, boto3

I'm trying to resize an image via using the `thumbnail()/resize()` functions and I know that this `thumbnail()` returns `NoneType` because it does it's magic in place and not creates a copy. I've tried a few options:
Note: I don't want to save it to local, this is gonna be sent to `s3`

`original_image` is a filestorage and it's coming from a `form`.

Try 1:

```
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

def resize_img(original_image, size):
    sizes = {
        'thumbnail': (128, 128),
        'medium': (640, 640),
        'large': (1024, 1024)
    }

    im = Image.open(BytesIO(original_image.read()))
    return im.thumbnail(sizes[size], Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

returns `NoneType` and can't use it. Is there a way to make it return something usable?

Try 2:

```
wpercent = (sizes[size]/float(im.size[0]))
hsize = int((float(im.size[1])*float(wpercent)))
return im.resize((sizes[size], hsize), Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

Returns `<class 'PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile'>` but `boto3` complains that this `Fileobj must implement read`

What are my options here?

Comment: [`.thumbnail()`](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.0.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.thumbnail) does in-place modification of the Image and returns `None` as documented. "*If you need to use the full resolution image as well, apply this method to a copy() of the original image*"

Comment: @dhke That's what I said above as well. The question is; how can I create a new image after resizing so I can use it later.

Comment: [`.copy()`](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.0.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.copy)? See (now) quoted excerpt from the docs ;-)

Comment: ``.thumbnail()`` modified the image you already had.  So ``return im`` would do what you're asking.  ``.resize()`` does actually return the new image, so the problem there is that the caller doesn't WANT an image; it wants a file(-like object) containing an image.  You could ``.save()`` the image into a ``BytesIO`` object, perhaps.

Comment: @jasonharper returning `im` seems like gonna do the trick but I still got `Fileobj must implement read` since I have no idea how to save the image into `BytesIO` obj. Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I come up with a solution. Thanks to @jasonharper

```
def resize_img(original_image, size):
    sizes = {
        'thumbnail': (128, 128),
        'medium': (640, 640),
        'large': (1024, 1024)
    }

    im = Image.open(BytesIO(original_image.read()))
    img = im.copy()

    img.thumbnail(sizes[size], Image.ANTIALIAS)
    byte_io = BytesIO()
    img.save(byte_io, 'JPEG')
    byte_io.seek(0)
    return byte_io
```

This solution works and `boto3` doesn't complain as well.

Answer (score 1):

I see from your code above you are also trying to:

```
return im.thumbnail(sizes[size], Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

but, `Image.thumbnail` is an in-place operation that returns `None`. You'd need something like:

```
im.thumbnail(sizes[size], Image.ANTIALIAS)
return im
```

You may want to do a `.copy()` of the original image to do this as well.

P.S. `sizes[size]` needs to be a tuple. It is in your example. I'm just stating because I have personally made that mistake several times. :)